# How to use "when" vs. "while" on the following occasions?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, conjunctions

Please have a look at these sentence pairs:

> 1. - When I worked as a teacher, I met a good friend.
>    - While I was working as a teacher, I met a good friend.
> 2. - When I had a dream, I thought of the idea.
>    - While I was having a dream, I thought of the idea.

Which ones are correct? And why?

Comment: The when variant in the first case, the while variant in the second. You didn't meet the friend while you were working, just generally at the time when you were a teacher. And you had more than one dream in your life, while "when I had a dream" suggests you only dreamt once. That being said, I'd swap around or even completely reword the dream sentence.

Comment: Better on ell.se ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I worked as a teacher, I met a good friend.

This sentence means, "During the time of my life *when I worked as a teacher*, I met a good friend."

> While I was working as a teacher, I met a good friend.

This sentence means, "While I was *on duty* working as a teacher, I met a good friend."

The difference is that "when" is referring to a time or period of your life and "while" is referring to the act of working as a teacher. Both could be correct depending on context.

---

> When I had a dream, I thought of the idea.

This sentence is rather meaningless. "When" doesn't really refer to a specific time or period and, therefore, isn't an appropriate use of the word.

> While I was having a dream, I thought of the idea.

This sentence means, "While I was *actively dreaming*, I thought of the idea."

The difference between "when" and "while is the same as before. "When" should be used to refer to specific time periods or eras; "while" should be used to refer to a particular activity or behavior.